# Python Write single row to multiple rows

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
ParentID, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4,Field5
1,a b,c,d   
2,e,f           
3,g,h,i     
4,j,k,l,m,n
5,o,p
```

I would like to be able to reformat it so that each "field" character has its own row like so:

```
ParentID,Field
1,a
1,b
1,c
1,d
2,e
2,f
```

I have over 1,500 lines. Is there a way using python CSV Read and Write to do something like this? I have used this before to do the opposite so I feel this can be done systematically

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a simple nested loop do this?

Read in your CSV as a list of lists and then write the data to a new CSV using a nested loop structure. The outer loop is reading through each list, grabbing the first element, the inner loop is formatting the data and appending it to your csv.

```
for each list in lists
    row_builder = first element
    for each remaining item in list
        row_builder += (delimiter + item)
        append to file
```